# How to verify if GIT branch can be merged fast-forward only without actual merging?

Tags: git, merge

I tried to find GIT command to merge with fast-forward only option and auto create merged commit but --ff-only not create auto commit.

Due to the fact that I want to make sure that I can do fast forward only and also create the commit after merging.

Unfortunate, these commands cannot help me to overcome this problem.
 - --ff-only, do fast-forward merge but not create commit
 - --no-ff, create auto commit but not stop merging if it cannot apply fast-forward.

Therefore, I tried to find any commands that can verify if it can merge fast-forward and then merge with auto commit.

Please give me some suggestion on this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you really only want to fast forward the destination branch, then maybe you should consider rebasing the feature on the target.  This would ensure that you only fast-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to fast-forward merge only, and **do** want a merge commit, then the following seems to work, even though it sounds ridiculously contradictory:

```
git merge [branch] --ff-only --no-ff
```

The reason it works is that `--no-ff` actually means "Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward." It doesn't mean "do not perform a fast-forward."

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tested and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

If there are no revisions in the current branch that are not already in the other, then merging from the other branch will result in a fast-forward. One way to check that:

```
git rev-list other..
```

Notice the `..` after the name of the other branch, it's important.

If the output is empty, then there are no commits in this branch not in `other`, and `git merge other` will result in a fast-forward.

Or, as [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) wrote in a comment, for shell script testing, use the status result of `git merge-base --is-ancestor`:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor HEAD foo; then
    echo merging foo can be done by advancing to foo without a merge
else
    echo merging foo would require a merge commit
fi
```

Comment: Or, for shell script testing, use the status result of `git merge-base --is-ancestor`: `if git merge-base --is-ancestor HEAD foo; then echo merging foo can be done by advancing to foo without a merge; else echo merging foo would require a merge commit; fi`

Comment: Thanks @torek, added that