# Git: require fast-forwardable merges, but don't fast-forward

Tags: git, merge, fast-forward

I'd like to have a policy in a project where pull requests are only accepted if they can be fast-forward merges, *but* I actually want to create a merge commit when merging.

In other words, use the validation part of the `--ff-only` flag, but when creating the commit, act as if `--no-ff` had been used.  This would go a long way to helping us keep our history graph clean, encourage people to use `git pull --rebase` when possible, etc.

Does someone know of a way this can be achieved?  In general our environments are using at least Git 2.8, and we're using Bitbucket Server (hosted onsite) for our repositories.

Comment: A *pull request* is where Bob says "I've pushed my changes somewhere you can reach, but not into the thing you *control*, and now I'd like you to take my changes". So you can easily check for fast-forward-ability, and then do a real merge: that's *your* job as the one approving or rejecting Bob's request. It's not clear to me if you're asking if Bitbucket Server (whatever that is) has a canned solution for this, or what.

Comment: The question is about how to enforce this policy on the server being pushed to.  I mention Bitbucket because it'd be great if they supported something like it, but a general solution using hooks/triggers/whatever would probably be relevant to more people.

Comment: I'm actually looking now for the same functionality. The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296227/how-to-verify-if-git-branch-can-be-merged-fast-forward-only-without-actual-mergi/41296494#41296494 says to do `git merge [branch] --ff-only --no-ff`, but this is not really working for me (git version 2.25.1), as a non-forwardable branch gets happily merged it I try that. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @AngeldeVicente the solution I found was to switch from Bitbucket to GitLab, which supports this use case natively by choosing the "Merge commit with semi-linear history" option.

Comment: @KenWilliams thanks. I knew about that feature in GitLab, but I was hoping there would be a way to do it for a local repository. But at least with present git functionality it looks like this is not possible. Cheers